# Probabilistic game involving tiles and patterns

Tags: probability

This is a probability question related to a board game. You   basically had to compute the probability of winning (by selecting the optimum strategy). The game was that you have tiles with patterns underneath and to win you have to flip two tiles with the same figure underneath. (a)The first game is with 4 tiles and 2 patterns. (b)The second game is with 6 tiles and 2 patterns.

I have no idea how to proceed with this question.

Thank You

Comment: Four tiles : choose two. If they are the same stop. If they are not oponent will win. He turns one of the remaining two and then picks the one he remembers to be the same from your first try. This is possible since there is only two symbols.

Comment: 6 tiles gives the same solution.

Comment: These answer is quite simple is this makes me wonder if I understood right. Will change comments to answer if I did not make any mistake grasping the rules.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Thanks. So what would the probabilities of winning be in each case?

Comment: Who starts to play first?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGagnon We do.

Comment: In both cases the oponent will win in the second turn for sure. So the probability of winning is the probability of turning two tiles of the same color on the first time.